# Get related data from database after EF Core migration

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm new to using C#, ASP.NET Core and Entity Framework Core.

I already created two entities in the database with EF Core, my tables are:

`Advertiser` table:

```
+--------------+---------+-----------+
| AdvertiserId |  Name   | AddressId |
+--------------+---------+-----------+
|            1 | Samsung |         1 |
|            2 | Apple   |         2 |
+--------------+---------+-----------+
```

The table above has a foreign key with an `Address` table:

```
+-----------+-----------------------+---------------+-------+
| AddressId |     AddressLine1      |     City      | State |
+-----------+-----------------------+---------------+-------+
|         1 | 427 North 44th Street | Phoenix       | AR    |
|         2 | 977 Orland Points     | New Raphaelle | CA    |
+-----------+-----------------------+---------------+-------+
```

In my advertiser service I want to get from database from advertisers table, but I also want to get `AddressLine1, City and State` from the `Address` table

Service:

```
public async Task<IList<Advertiser>> GetActiveAsync()
{
    return await _db.Advertisers.ToListAsync();
}
```

But this only get the values from advertisers table (the model that I used is the same one I used for the migration)

Advertiser model used for migration:

```
public class Advertiser
{
    public int AdvertiserId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    public Address? Address { get; set; }
    public int AddressId { get; set; }
}
```

How can I get values from address table too? Thanks in advance

Comment: The docs may help here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/?

Comment: Try with Include - like this: `return await _db.Advertisers.Include(a => a.Address).ToListAsync();`

Answer (score 0):

Couple changes needed but you are well on your way.

You may want to change you Advertiser Entity to have a virtual Address property, and decorate that with the ForeignKey attribute:

```
public class Advertiser
{
    public int AdvertiserId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    
    [ForeignKey(nameof(AddressId))]
    public virtual Address Address { get; set; }
    
    public int AddressId { get; set; }
}
```

In your dbcontext, in OnModelCreating method, you should setup your entity:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
...
modelBuilder.Entity<Advertiser>(e =>
    {
        e.HasKey(x => x.AdvertiserId);
        e.HasOne(x => x.Address);
    });
...
}
```

Now in your GetActiveAsync method you can simply include the address when querying Advertisers:

```
public async Task<IList<Advertiser>> GetActiveAsync()
{
    return await _db.Advertisers.Include(x => x.Address).ToListAsync();
}
```

EF Core thankfully disabled lazy loading by default. Explicitly including what you need will speed up queries but you have to pay attention to not run into objects that are not hydrated.